# ImGui don't recognize FreeGLUT?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, glut, freeglut, imgui

I am endeavoring to configure **Visual Studio Code** using the Python compiler with ImGui and freeglut.

In accordance with the official guidelines, I have configured **C++** on Visual Studio Code utilizing **MinGW**, which includes gcc, g++, and gdb. ( https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw )

Subsequently, I set up **OpenGL** with Visual Studio Code (I utilized **GLUT** and **GLEW**). At this point i have all configured properly.

When i'm trying to add **ImGui** to my setup i failed, a Python script is used to compile C++ code.

```python
import subprocess

file_name = "main"
include_dir = "dependencies/include"
lib_dir = "dependencies/lib"
lib = "-lglew32s -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lfreeglut"
imguih = "dependencies/include/*.h"
imguicpp = "dependencies/include/*.cpp"
preprocessor = "-DGLEW_STATIC"

def main():
subprocess.call(f"g++ {preprocessor} -c main.cpp -I{include_dir}")
subprocess.call(f"g++ {preprocessor} *.o -o {file_name} -L{lib_dir} {lib} -g {imguih} {imguicpp}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have a public repository with my failed attempt: https://github.com/Jojaror/imGui-OpenGL-setup

The issue arises when the compiler processes the file imgui_impl_glut.cpp and fails to recognize the GL/freeglut.h file. If I remove this implementation and subsequently eliminate its usage from my code (which essentially means only checking the version of imgui), everything functions as expected. Therefore, it seems to me that the problem lies in imgui not being able to locate my freeglut header. However, I am uncertain about how to specify its location.

From my perspective, I have already directed the compiler to the location of my freeglut files. Without imGui, everything functions correctly. All other imGui files operate as anticipated, with the exception of the ImGui implementation file for glut.

```
dependencies/include/imgui_impl_glut.cpp:44:10: fatal error: GL/freeglut.h: No such file or directory
   44 | #include <GL/freeglut.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Any assistance?

Comment: Why does your second `subprocess.call` not include the `include_dir`? Both calls are standalone, they do not transfer any information to each other

Comment: g++ cannot specify '-c' with multiple files

Comment: I feel it would probably be easier for you to spend a few hours and learn a minimal amount of CMake and use that instead of attempting to roll your own python build script. CMake is used in many opensource projects today.

Comment: If you really want to roll your own python script you should executed these commands in a MinGW shell first. I can see that there are multiple problems on this line:  `subprocess.call(f"g++ {preprocessor} *.o -o {file_name} -L{lib_dir} {lib} -g {imguih} {imguicpp}")` the source files should be before the libraries and you didn't set the include directory. Also I am not sure about the *.o part in combination of compiling the source files with {imguicpp}

Comment: I have tried in multiple ways, but same result at any order, using the python script.